# javaslang/Vavr : How to do a try with resource

Tags: java-8, try-with-resources, vavr

Here is my code snippet :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Try.of(Main::getLines)
            .onFailure(cause -> log.error("An error has occurred while parsing the file", cause));
}

private static List<Fiche> getLines() {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get("insurance_sample.csv"))
            .skip(1)
            .map(Main::toPojo)
            .filter(fiche -> fiche.getPointLongitude().equals(-81.711777))
            .peek(fiche -> log.info("Fiche added with success {}", fiche))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'm getting Use try-with-resources or close this "Stream" in "finally" clause. on this line `Files.lines(Paths.get("insurance_sample.csv"))`

Anyone can help me to use a try-with-resources using Vavr?

Comment: `Try.withResources`?

Comment: Try.withResources is expecting a CheckefFunction and the getLines method is returning a List

Answer (score 7):

Wrap the call to `Files#lines(Path)` into `Try#withResources` like so:

```
List<String> lines = Try.withResources(() -> Files.lines(Paths.get("/hello.csv")))
        .of(stream -> stream.collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .getOrElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Something's wrong!"));
```